# How can i import the code from a py file to my php page?

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm doing this for a school project, basically I've go a bunch of .py files on my database and I want to import them to my page as text.

The page should look like this:

`print("Ciao Mondo")`

"download source code"
"description"

I don't want to do a simple copy and paste if there is a way not to do it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the [`file_get_contents` function](https://php.net/file_get_contents)? This will let you read a file into a variable, which you can the output where you need it.

Comment: Solved it with file() since i will have more rows, thank you a lot